# Как показать сегодняшнюю дату?

Tags: php

Как показать сегодняшнюю дату? `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time())` вроде помог, но он почему то постоянно показывает число 1970-01-1 03:00
Функция `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time())` показывает дату у пользователя или сервера? Если у пользователя, то как сделать, чтобы показывало у сервера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

показывает дату сервера.

**upd**

избавится от секунд:
**php**

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($row['date']));
//или 
echo substr($row['date'],0,-3);
```

**mysql**

```
   select date_format(date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as date from table
```

Comment: Поставил date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), при вставке в бд почему вставляется лишь Y-m-d, при выводе даты из бд выводится 1970-01-1 03:00. Запрос для вывода date("Y-m-j H:i", $row['date']);
Тип поля date

Comment: в бд нужно поменять тип поля на `TIMESTAMP` а для вывода в этом случае не надо использовать функцию date()

Comment: спасибо, все отлично. Только как убрать секунды? Из запроса вставки убрал. а он вместо секунд ставит 00

Comment: в базе, никак, просто не выводите их

Comment: Я время изменил на $time = date("Y-m-d H:i");, а он все равно секунды вставляет, только не реальные, а 00. Как не выводить? Если обратно сделать date("Y-m-j H:i", $row['date']), то он опять выводит 1970-01-1 03:00. Если просто $row['date'] то будет 2012-04-12 22:59:00

Comment: если $row['date'] пустая , то он выведет 1 01 1970